# Performance of byte[] in Entity Framework query

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an Entity Framework data query in an MVC application.
One of the fields that is selected is a byte[] which contains an image.
When I have this field in the query the speed of the query is very slow, around 30 seconds, without the field it takes around 2 seconds. 
I know this will to be to do with loading the data into memory.
I was wondering if anyone has any ideas as to how to speed this query up without any large design changes. Am I missing something simple?

Here is the query...

```
            var tiles = (from t in context.Tiles
                     join o in tileIds on t.TileId equals o
                     join u in context.aspnet_Users on t.UserId equals u.UserId
                     join c in context.Checkins on t.UserId equals c.UserId
                     where t.AdminDeactivated == false
                     select new TileLite()
            {
                Title = t.Title,
                Quote1 = t.Quote1,
                TileId = t.TileId,
                LikeCount = t.LikeCount,
                SafeUserName = u.SafeUserName,
                UserId = u.UserId,
                ClientUpdateTime = t.ClientUpdateTime,
                URLUserName = u.URLUserName,
                CheckinTime = c.CheckinTime,
                Latitude = c.Latitude,
                Longitude = c.Longitude,
                ProfilePhoto = u.Photo,
                TileImage = t.BgImage
            });
```

The field that is causing the issue is...

```
  TileImage = t.BgImage
```

Comment: if its mvc app, why do you need to load image there? If you need to display it, then load it in another action where image is requested. The idea is to don't load bytes if you don't need them.

Comment: You could store the images not in the database, and just store the path heh.

Comment: I'm not sure if you consider this a large design change, but one option is to store the image on a file server, and store the location of the file in your db.

Comment: Just store the uri of an image, and then <img src="storedUrl" />, this way borwsers will load your images async, and cache them.

Comment: You create a `TileLite`. Lite - I wouldn't expect an image to be in there altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your responses. The answer was a combination of them all.

I removed the image from being stored the database and stored it in Azure Blob Storage using the userId as a key.

Now I have been able to remove it from my sql queries which as sped them up no end.

Thank you.